# Context Help for EWZ_SEARCH bundle Symfony Jobeet 2.3 to 2.8 upgrade

Tags: php, symfony, lucene

A while back I completed this series of tutorials and converted the jobeet from symfony 1 to symfony 2.

http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/07/symfony2-jobeet-day-1-starting-up-the-project/

I am now trying to upgrade it to 2.8

Everything works except for the lucene search.

I am attempting to implement EWZSearchBundle as a solution.

config.yml

```
ewz_search:
    indices:
        indexJob:
            path:                 %kernel.root_dir%/EwzLuceneIndices/%kernel.environment%/myIndexJob
            analyzer:             Zend\Search\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\Utf8\CaseInsensitive

    # deprecated
    analyzer:             Zend\Search\Lucene\Analysis\Analyzer\Common\TextNum\CaseInsensitive
    path:                 %kernel.root_dir%/cache/%kernel.environment%/lucene/index
```

search action in controller

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $this->getRequest()->get('query');

        if(!$query) {
            if(!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ibw_job'));
            } else {
                return new Response('No results.');
            }
        }

        $jobs = $em->getRepository('AcmeJobeetBundle:Job')->getForLuceneQuery($query);

        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            if('*' == $query || !$jobs || $query == '') {
                return new Response('No results.');
            }

            return $this->render('AcmeJobeetBundle:Job:list.html.twig', array('jobs' => $jobs));
        }

    }
```

function in entity repository

```
 static public function getLuceneIndex()
    {
       $luceneSearchForFooIndex = $this->get('ewz_search.lucene.manager')->getIndex('indexJob');

        return $luceneSearchForFooIndex ;
    }
```

The error that I get in app_dev.php

```
 Error: Using $this when not in object context
500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException
```

I know that "$this" is out of context and that is why I am getting the error but I have absolutely no id on how to fix it.

Any help/links to docs/ideas for a solution is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Composer Saved the Day

```
     "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
     "zf1/zend-search-lucene": "~1.12"
```

After a day or so of trying to make the other search functions work. I was able to the the zend framework work by adding the specific framework component through composer.

It now all works in 2.8.